# Implementation of java.nio.FileSystem wrapping Commons VFS?

Tags: java, java-7, java-8, nio2, apache-commons-vfs

I know there exists [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) which permits to connect to different `FileSystem`, where a `FileSystem` may be something like a FTP, HTTP, SFTP, Zip file or simply a local file system.

I am wondering, after some search (most on Google and VFS site) that resulted in nothing, is there were an implementation of `java.nio.FileSystem` that would wrap VFS.

My use case is the following: I have a personal project where I need to read file content, or list directory content, to do something with this content (such as indexing, etc).

I am currently using `java.nio.Path` to represent the path of file I am reading, and I'd like to add later a feature to work with a SSH connection (I have no need for this "now", but the question still interests me).

Comment: If it isn't a requirement then why trying to bolt it on already? If you don't need it you don't need it, don't add feature because they are nice or might be needed somehwere in the possible future... Adding things that aren't used is basically adding technical debt and additional maintaince for code that is never used.

Comment: It  is  a  personal project I'm working on - I won't say there is no technical debt, but it is less important.
Working  with  Java  NIO  is  easier  for  me,  and  perhaps  my  question  is  misworded:  I'm looking for an
implementation  of  NIO  `FileSystem`  that  would wrap Commons VFS. Then, I won't need to change my code that
much _if_ I were implementing this feature.

Comment: There, I reworded my question

Comment: Writing this wrapper could be another interesting project ;)

Comment: It sure would be an interesting project. I'll try that when I'll need it, and if this question is not answered ;)

Comment: @NoDataFound did you find or implement a solution? can you share the answer (I'm looking for a FileSystem wrapper for VFS's `ram`) ?

Comment: I did not implements a wrapper, nor did I found a solution.

Comment: @bachr Look at https://github.com/google/jimfs

Comment: As for my question, I found that https://truevfs.java.net/ does all that I needed.

Comment: thanks @TavianBarnes for point to that project